# Disable tooltip in CanvasJS Combination Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, canvasjs

Is it possible to disable tooltips for only one series in a combination chart of canvasjs below?

```
  data: [
  {
      type: "area",
      color: "red",        // change color here
      fillOpacity: 1,
      dataPoints: [
    { x: 0, y: 100 },
    { x: 100, y: 100 }
    ]
  },
    {
        type: "area",
        color: "yellow",
        toolTipContent: " ",
        dataPoints: [
    { x: 0, y: 10 },
    { x: 100, y: 100 }
    ]
    }
 ]
```

Here is the link to my fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/Abhishek1191/s71djz9m/2

I have four separate series plotted inside the fiddle. 3 Area and 1 line. If anyone may let me know if I can disable tooltips for area series.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting toolTipContent to empty string, set toolTipContent to null which will disable the toolTip for individual dataPoint / dataSeries. In your jsfiddle you are using v1.4.1 which does not support this feature. Please download the latest version. Here is the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/s71djz9m/5/) .

```
var  chart =  new  CanvasJS.Chart("container",
{
    data: [
    {
        toolTipContent: null,
        type: "column",
        dataPoints:[
            { x: 10, y: 20}
        ]
    }
    ]
});
chart.render();
```